# How do I to create charts wizard in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I have created charts using the Microsoft Chart controls for my asp.net web application.

Now i need develop a chart wizard where based on the result set the graphs will be plotted dynamically i.e to invoke a chart wizard at run time where the user selects the parameters for the coordinates and type of chart based on the parameters graph will be plotted.

Also can any one suggest if any tool is already available.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well regardless the chart control itself and the parameters you want to capture in the various steps I think the starting point should be on how to make a multi paged/ multi spep Wizard navigation in ASP.NET webforms.

there are some interesting links:

[The ASP.NET 2.0 Wizard Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163894.aspx)

[ASP.NET 2.0 Wizard Control](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/02/21/438732.aspx)

hope this helps, if you wanted to do this in MVC there are also articles and samples available:

[how to make a wizard with ASP.Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297148/how-to-make-a-wizard-with-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion i did the charts using the wizard control.